# Uber Ride Request using API

Tags: android, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber Login and Ride Request using Uber APIs. I have successfully completed the Login part and trying to integrate the Ride Request part. Below is my code snippet for that -

```
  SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                // mandatory
                .setClientId("abc")
                // required for enhanced button features
                .setServerToken("xyz")
                // required for implicit grant authentication
                .setRedirectUri("https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize")
                // required scope for Ride Request Widget features
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST))
                // optional: set Sandbox as operating environment
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .build();

        UberSdk.initialize(config);

        OAuth2Credentials credentials = new OAuth2Credentials.Builder()
                .setSessionConfiguration(config)
                **.build();**

        try {
            String authorizationUrl = credentials.getAuthorizationUrl();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Credential credential = credentials.authenticate(authorizationCode, userId); 
        CredentialsSession session = new CredentialsSession(config, credential);
        RidesService service = UberRidesApi.with(session).createService();
```

Whenever I run this and try to check the Log, it crashes in the OAuth's .build() line.

Here is the error I am getting -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client ID and secret must be set.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client ID and secret must be set.
                                                                                    at com.uber.sdk.rides.client.utils.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:66)
                                                                                    at com.uber.sdk.rides.auth.OAuth2Credentials$Builder.validate(OAuth2Credentials.java:170)
                                                                                    at com.uber.sdk.rides.auth.OAuth2Credentials$Builder.build(OAuth2Credentials.java:181)
                                                                                    at com.rahul.uberapi.android.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:119)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

But I have already set the Client Id and Secret.

Absolutely confused with what is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues is the redirect uri you are using. This should be set in the developer dashboard and it represents the url we redirect a user to after successfully authorizing the application. Please see the example below:

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
.setClientId("<CLIENT_ID>")
.setClientSecret("<CLIENT_SECRET>")
.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX)
.setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST))
.setRedirectUri("<REDIRECT_URI>")
.build();

 OAuth2Credentials credentials = new OAuth2Credentials.Builder()
.setSessionConfiguration(config)
.build();

 String authorizationUrl = credentials.getAuthorizationUrl();
```

See the relevant java api tutorial for a working example: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/java

Comment: What should be the redirect URI ? I'm using "http://localhost:8000/" for now, will this work ? I've registered same redirect uri on uber developer account